# "Open shaming of anyone..."

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context

> ***Open*** ***shaming*** of anyone who spoke out discouraged responsible dissent.

How does ***open*** with shaming work, grammatically and meaningfully?

Is ***discouraged*** modifying "responsible dissent?

Answer (score 1):

I think open here is adjective to modify shaming, verb=discouraged, object=dissent. shaming is used as gerund.

Answer (score 1):

Overall meaning of this sentence:
Whenever someone publicly criticized the authority the sentence is referencing, the authority would publicly humiliate that person. This made people wary of going against that authority.

Grammatically:
"shaming" - subject
"discouraged" - verb
"dissent" - object

"open" - adjective modifying shaming (approximately means "publicly" in this context or just "in front of others")
"of anyone who spoke out" - modifies shaming
"responsible" - modifies dissent (seems like you figured this part out)

Comment: @why is not in this form: spoke out **discouraging** responsible dissent. Instead of use **discouraged** because usually, as it's know, gerund come after verb.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, [*open*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/open) means:

> 9. adjective - [ADJECTIVE noun]
>      If you describe a situation, attitude, or way of behaving as open, you mean it is not kept hidden or secret.

So "Open shaming" refers to shaming that occurs in public. Such publicity might negatively impact the individual(s) involved.

Answer (score 1):

> Open shaming of anyone who spoke out discouraged responsible dissent.

The subject of this sentence is the noun phrase *open shaming of anyone who spoke out*.  In this phrase, the head noun is *shaming*, a noun derived from the gerund form *shaming*.  We can tell it's a noun because it takes an adjective as a modifier (*open*) and an *of*-PP (preposition phrase) as a complement, corresponding to the direct object of the verb *shame*, which in this case would be *anyone who spoke out*.

As others have explained, *open* here is an adjective meaning 'public', and describes the way the shaming was done.  We tend to strongly anticipate and avoid shame, so public shaming is a way to influence and control the behavior of others.  In this case, people were less likely to dissent (speak out in protest) because they were afraid of being shamed openly.

The verb here is *discouraged*, and its direct object is *responsible dissent*.  Verbs do not modify their direct objects, so no, it is not a modifier.

Comment: Why after **spoke** **out** does discouraged come. Why is not in this way: spoke out "discouraging" responsible dissent.

Comment: @BavyanYaldo The verb in this sentence is *discouraged*.  If we simplify the sentence, it looks like *Shaming discouraged dissent.*  In the original sentence, the phrasal verb *spoke out* is part of the relative clause *who spoke out*, which is part of the noun phrase *anyone who spoke out*.